# kendo ui grid: Compare data in multiple selected rows?

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui

Ok, rephrasing the question here, it seems the articulation was lacking.

I have a kendo ui grid, and when I make multiple selections (2 or more at a time) of rows, I need to compare values of a specific column in all the selected rows to determine if they are exactly equal(same) or not. Here's is my kendo 'change: ' function, the dataItem in question we'll call 'fancyNumber':

```
change: function(e) {
    var selectedRows = this.select();
    var selectedDataItems = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < selectedRows.length; i++) {
      var dataItem = this.dataItem(selectedRows[i]);
      selectedDataItems.push(dataItem);
    }

    var selected = $.map(this.select(), function(item) {
       return $(item).text();
    });

function allValuesSame() {
    for (var i = 1; i < selectedRows.length; i++)
    {
        if(this[i] != this[0])
        return false;
    }
    return true;
    }

if (selected.length > 1){
    var selectedRows = $("#myTable").data("kendoGrid").select();
    var fancyNumberText = this.dataItem(this.select()).fancyNumber
    if (allValuesSame(fancyNumberText) === true) {
        alert(fancyNumberText); //just testing to see what I get
    }
    return allValuesSame(fancyNumberText);
    }



    if (selected.length == 0) {
    $('#fancyButton').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
} else if (selected.length == 1) {
    $('#fancyButton').attr('disabled', false);
} else if (selected.length > 1 && allValuesSame == true) {
    $('#fancyButton').attr('disabled', false);
}
```

},

Clearly, this isn't correct; how do I do this?

Comment: Updated, rephrased question with new code..

Answer (score 0):

You can use the .dataSource property to get the model that your grid is bound to and make the comparison there.

http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid#fields-dataSource

Say your grid has an Id of myDataGrid, you would use:

```
var gridModel = $("#myDataGrid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.data();

// Sample comparison
if (gridModel[3].someField === gridModel[5].someField) {
    // Do something with your buttons
}
```

Comment: Thank you; I understand that, but how do I, for example, compare from say, 10 rows that are selected; I don't necessarily know where they exist in the dom..?

Comment: I see.  According to the docs, (http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid#methods-select), the .select() method will return all the selected rows.  So you would do something like var selectedRows = $("#myDataGrid").data("kendoGrid").select();

Answer (score 0):

You need to set up the grid with the following...

```
.Selectable(sel => sel.Mode(GridSelectionMode.Multiple))
.Events(e => e.Change("onChange"))
```

Once you have these in place, you can select individual lines and you have an event which is called on selection `onChange`

In your script, wire up this funciton...

```
function onChange() {
  //you can get the selected row like this
  var selected = $.map(this.select(), function(item) {
        return item.getAttribute('data-uid');
    });

  //if selected count > 1 then check logic and enable/disable button
  EnableDisableButton(true, "#myButton");//assuming condition was good
}
```

You need to set up the `onChange` to record the rows values from each selection, maybe using an array and then comparing the values in the array.

```
function EnableDisableButton(isToBeEnabled, buttonName) {

    if (isToBeEnabled)
        $(buttonName).removeAttr("disabled").removeClass("k-state-disabled");
    else
        $(buttonName).prop("disabled", true).addClass("k-state-disabled");
}
```

Comment: hi! thanks.. I'm doing most of that already, I'm not after the row data-uid, but rather a numeric string within a column, in this case, I'm just grabbing $('#myTable :nth-child(3)').text(); also in IE9 (yikes) so, not using .getAttribute()...